# Process request of cURL

Tags: php, api, curl

I made a cURL request code and i'd like to process the data it sends.

cURL code:

```
            $url = "http://rbvconsultancy.com/api/post.php";
            $xml_builder = '<?xml version = "1.0" ?>
            <request>
                <no>1</no><dat>hello</dat>
            </request>';

            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_builder);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 28);
            $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
            $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $curl_error = curl_error($ch);
            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            $rest = $ch_result;
            echo $rest;
```

process cURL:

```
echo "hello".$_GET['para1'];
```

Based on the code above, i'd like my process cURL code to get the value of `$xml_builder`. Any ideas on how to do it? It seems that `$_GET['para1']` doesnt do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want this :

you can copy this to your response PHP file

```
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Maybe this will help you